# SQL Server: Compare two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns in a SQL table as follow. I need to compare these two columns for mismatches but due to extra decimals i am getting false results. When i try to convert the first column it gives the error

> "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

How to solve this issue? The length of first column varies.

```
Column01(varchar)   Column02(Decimal)
0.01                0.010000  
0.255               0.255000
```

Comment: What DBMS are you actually using?  SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012?  Tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have data in `Column01` that cannot be casted to `DECIMAL`.

With **`SQL Server 2012+`** I would use **[`TRY_PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)**:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE Column02 = TRY_PARSE(Column01 AS DECIMAL(38,18));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395701)**</kbd>

When value from column cannot be casted safely you get `NULL`.

For **`SQL Server 2008`** you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tab
WHERE (CASE 
          WHEN ISNUMERIC(Column01) = 1 THEN CAST(Column01 AS DECIMAL(38,18))
          ELSE NULL
      END) = Column02;
```

**EDIT:**

If you need it at column level use:

```
SELECT Column01, Column02,
   CASE WHEN Column02 = TRY_PARSE(Column01 AS DECIMAL(38,18))
          OR (Column02 IS NULL AND Column01 IS NULL)
        THEN 'true'
        ELSE 'false'
    END AS [IsEqual]
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395715)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using self join and conversion function

```
SELECT x.Column01, y.Column02
FROM table1 x, table1 y
WHERE x.Column02 = try_parse(y.Column01 as decimal(38,18))
```

Since I cannot comment, I like to thank lad2025 for showing live demo and introducing to data.stackexchange for composing queries

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing it:

```
create  table #temp(col1 varchar(10),col2 decimal(10,6))
insert into #temp values(0.01,0.010000 ),(0.255,0.255000),(0.25,25),(0.555,10.0)
select * from #temp where REPLACE(REPLACE(col2,col1,''),0,'')  = ''
select * from #temp where REPLACE(REPLACE(col2,col1,''),0,'')  <> ''
```